# Audio pause/play

Tags: jquery, html, audio

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var playing = false;
    var audioElement = document.createElement('audio');
    audioElement.setAttribute('src', 'star.mp3');
    $('#star').click(function() {
    playing == true;
    if(playing == true) audioElement.pause();
    else audioElement.play();
    });
});
```

What it is meant to do is that when one sound is playing and I click on the other sound the sound that already plays should stop and the other should start.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is here:

```
$('#star').click(function() {
    playing == true; // should be = not == if you're trying to assign 
    if(playing == true) audioElement.pause(); // but if you assign then playing is always true
    else audioElement.play();
    });
```

See [assignment operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators)
and [comparison operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators)

Here's a simplified version that may help:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var audio1 = $("#DunDunDun")[0];
  var audio2 = $("#WaWaWaa")[0];
  $("#ominousMusic").click(function() {
    audio1.play();
    audio2.pause();
  });
  $("#sadMusic").click(function() {
    audio2.play();
    audio1.pause()
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ominousMusic" title="go on, click it, you know you want to...">
  cue ominous music...
</div>
<audio id="DunDunDun">
  <source src="http://pluggedinwebdesign.com/media/DunDunDun.mp3">
    Your browser isn't invited to super fun audio time.
</audio>
<div id="sadMusic" title="go on, click it, you know you want to...">
  cue sad music...
</div>
<audio id="WaWaWaa">
  <source src="http://pluggedinwebdesign.com/media/Sad_Trombone.mp3">
    Your browser isn't invited to super fun audio time.
</audio>
```